# как перевести проект с Verge 3D на Three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

Есть проект сделанный на  Verge 3D и нужно способ как его перевести на Three js кто нибудь знает как перевести?

Comment: Можно попробовать обратиться к разработчику: https://discourse.threejs.org/u/yurikovelenov/summary

Comment: так и сделаю спасибо!